# How to handle the ubuntu updates?

Tags: ubuntu

I'm new to Ubuntu. Every week ubuntu has some update messages to download. I'm afraid that if I download all the updates every time, my disk will be full after a year or two. But if I close the updates, I may miss some important messages.

How should I handle the updates?

Comment: +1 Close; Off Topic.  This question belongs on serverfault.com

Comment: @UnkwnTech - Agree with off topic, but it belongs on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) rather than Server Fault.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName I'll agree, I tend to forget about the non-trilogy sites.  In this case I should have remembered I had a debate with Atwood about weather or not the Ubuntu site should exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with aserwin, but for slightly different reasoning.

Ubuntu SECURITY updates are intended to fix problems with existing functionality.  By ignoring the updates, you leave your system vulnerable to potential malware or intrusions.  You always have ultimate control of the updates (since they require your password to run), but unless your system is very small and in danger of running out of hard drive space, there really is no good reason to block the updates.

The only time you need to be concerned about the amount of space required is when you update Ubuntu from one version to the next.  In cases like this, you need enough space to download the updates before they are applied.  For this reason, I generally advise my clients to stick with an Ubuntu long term release (LTS) version so they won't be asked to update to a new version on a regular basis.

Comment: Ok,thank you! My ubuntu is 12.04LTS. And I have no worry about the disk volume now!